# What's the meaning of: "flutter : Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'"?

Tags: flutter, debugging

A user sent in a log file from one of my Flutter apps that got flooded with:

```
I flutter : Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
```

Timestamps of these messages are always 16/17 milliseconds apart from each other, indicating they're logged once per frame. Beside that, the app seems to work fine and there are no other errors/exceptions logged.

Question now is, what triggers these messages? And how to debug it without access to the troublesome device? What's `DiagnosticsProperty` even used for? Unfortunately the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/DiagnosticsProperty-class.html) ain't very helpful, so your advise is very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The first exception thrown should have a full message and stack trace

Comment: @Albert221 Thank you very much for the hint! Thant's a step forward...